# Clip super loud after embedding

Tags: premiere, audio

With Premiere Pro 14.8.0 on Mac OS I have a simple project. In one wequence I have 1 single video and one audio:

[image: Ending sequence]

The audio is nice and normalised, sounds perfectly all right.

Then I embed this sequence in an other sequence:

[image: Second sequence]

As you can see, Premiere does not show waveform any more, and although the volume adjustment is on 0 dB and I have no audio effects at all, also haven't touched the mixers, **the sound in the second sequence on this clip is crazy loud, you can barely recognise it from the distortion**. Even with -80dB it's pretty loud and distorted. All the other clips in the second seq are OK.

What can be the reason for this, is this a bug?

Comment: Restart did not help, but deleting the clip from the second sequence and then adding it once again solved it. I'm pretty sure this was a bug after all.